# Change Unity/Gnome Screensaver lock method to your own

Tags: gnome, login, login-screen, lock-screen

I'm wondering is there a way to change unlocking by typing password to some other methods: (for example like in android when you draw some pattern).
Is it possible to change it to my code.
If yes what should I look at, and where to find some documentation, descriptions?

Comment: When u try to change system defaults splash screen and login screen ..it is not sure if u will get ur system back properly...(this is not a solution but a suggestion)

Comment: Can you, please, clarify your suggestion?

Comment: Unity and Gnome are two different desktop environments [Edit your question title]

Comment: My point is not about exact desktop environment. What I want to know is it possible to change login/unlock methods for each of them. If yes then how.

Comment: Once i tried to load macintosh splash screen and login screen on my gnome desktop . Boom!i was given a warning but i did and neither mac splash screen came but my startup time was gone high and system was crashing again n again

Comment: And I'm wondering how to do it properly. To avoid system crashing. Perhaps changing to login screen written by yourself.

Comment: U cant set a pattern password like android in ubuntu :/..u can change lightdm theme by sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mbuntu-lightdm-v3

Comment: This one converts to mac login screen...but still u have to type the password